# Class does not conform to protocol, but struct does

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Both a struct and a class conforms to a protocol. I use 2 protocol extensions with `where` conditions to add an implementation of the var property for both class and struct.

I'm quite surprised to see a compile error for classes only.

Why does this happen for classes and not for structs?

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var property:String { get }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self == MyStruct {
    var property: String { return "" }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self == MyClass {
    var property: String { return "" }
}

struct MyStruct : MyProtocol {}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {} //Type 'MyClass' does not conform to protocol 'MyProtocol'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not compile because your

```
extension MyProtocol where Self == MyClass
```

provides a default method only for `MyClass` itself, but not for possible subclasses. Changing the constraint to

```
extension MyProtocol where Self: MyClass
```

makes the code compile. *Alternatively* prevent the creation of subclasses with

```
final class MyClass : MyProtocol {}
```

This is not a problem for `MyStruct` because struct types cannot be inherited from in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Classes can inherit from other classes.

So some class `X` may inherit from `MyClass`.

But your extension provides implementation of `MyProtocol` properties of if the class is `MyClass` and not it's descendant. So any class that inherits from `MyClass` won't have any properties of `MyProtocol` implemented. And that is the problem.

If you declare `MyClass` `final` your code would be valid:

```
final class MyClass : MyProtocol {}
```

If you extend conditional extension to any `MyClass` descendants your code would be valid:

```
extension MyProtocol where Self: MyClass {
    var property: String { return "" }
}
```

But right now all those potential subclasses lack implementation for `MyProtocol` and it is not allowed.